# Converting a for loop to foreach and return same structural order

Tags: r, foreach

Consider the following `for` loop:

```
x1 <- array(0, c(10, 20))
for(indv in 1:10)
{
  x1[indv,] <- cbind(c(1:10) * indv * 1.0, c(31:40))
}
array(x1)
```

Which gives the following output:

```
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10   2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18
 [20]  20   3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30   4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32
 [39]  36  40   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50   6  12  18  24  30  36  42
 [58]  48  54  60   7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70   8  16  24  32  40  48
 [77]  56  64  72  80   9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90  10  20  30  40  50
 [96]  60  70  80  90 100  31  31  31  31  31  31  31  31  31  31  32  32  32  32
[115]  32  32  32  32  32  32  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  34  34  34
[134]  34  34  34  34  34  34  34  35  35  35  35  35  35  35  35  35  35  36  36
[153]  36  36  36  36  36  36  36  36  37  37  37  37  37  37  37  37  37  37  38
[172]  38  38  38  38  38  38  38  38  38  39  39  39  39  39  39  39  39  39  39
[191]  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40
```

I tried converting it to a `foreach` loop as follows:

```
x2 <- foreach(indv = 1:10, .combine=rbind) %do% {
  cbind(c(1:10) * indv * 1.0, c(31:40))
}
array(x2)
```

Which gives the following output:

```
[1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10   2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18
 [20]  20   3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30   4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32
 [39]  36  40   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50   6  12  18  24  30  36  42
 [58]  48  54  60   7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70   8  16  24  32  40  48
 [77]  56  64  72  80   9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90  10  20  30  40  50
 [96]  60  70  80  90 100  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  31  32  33  34
[115]  35  36  37  38  39  40  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  31  32  33
[134]  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  31  32
[153]  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  31
[172]  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
[191]  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
```

This conversion is wrong since it gives different answers.
How do I do this conversion properly?

Comment: I think you're looking for something like `foreach(indv = 1:10, .combine =rbind) %dopar%
{c(1:10 * indv, c(31:40))}`. This is assuming you want to do things in parallel. If not, replace %dopar% with %do%

Comment: @Mark Could you elaborate?

Comment: Well, you're creating rows, but you're creating them by using cbind, which is for binding columns